why I get error when I use href="{{ panel.get_absolute.url }}" in my templates?
I wrote a simple page to show a list of goods that when you click on each of them it forwards you to the purpose page to show the good's details, but I think this method doesn't work right now or I have a mistake ...
this is my model:
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class PanelManager(models.Manager):
    def ye(self,year):
        return self.filter(publish__year=year)
    def pu(self,publish):
        return self.filter(status=publish)

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')



class Panel(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = PanelManager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    # objects = models.Manager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:details',args=[self.slug, self.id])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

my views:
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Panel


def test1(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello this is test1")

def panellist(request):
    panels=Panel.objects.filter(publish__year=2024)
    return render(request, 'users/panel/panel list.html',{'panels':panels})

def p_details(request,panel, pk):
    panel=get_object_or_404(Panel,slug=panel,id=pk)
    return render(request, 'users/panel/details.html', {'panel':panel})

my urls:
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('panellist/', views.panellist, name='panellist'),
    path('details/<slug:panel>/<int:pk>/', views.p_details, name='details'),

]

my template

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>second test</h1>
{% for panel in panels %}
    <a href="{{ panel.get_absolute_url }}">
        <h2>{{panel.title}} : {{panel.author}}   -   {{panel.status}}</h2>
    </a>

{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>

app installed:
enter image description here
my panel fields:
enter image description here
Then I got this error :
Error during template rendering
In template D:\Shahram\projects\New folder 4\D_newsite\templates\users\panel\panel list.html, error at line 10
'users' is not a registered namespace
10 <a href="{{ panel.get_absolute_url }}">

This is the problem:
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('users:details',args=[self.slug, self.id])

The error is telling you that it doesn't know about the prefix users: in that url name.
Your urls.py file contains a url named details, but not users:details.

It worked, Thank you. I think what I used was worked in earlier previous versions of Django.
